# Flutter not disposing memory properly after update

Tags: flutter

need suggestions as to what could be the potential solutions. I have recently made an extensive game on flutter using various assets and widgets. It was working fine however, since the new update my game keeps on crashing with a no memory error. Despite disposing the memory constantly, flutter does not properly dispose memory and it keeps on stacking. When i launch the application, i can clearly see the memory gradually increasing till the game crashes and i receive an 'aw snap' error. (My game is online based). Please do help out if you have experienced something similar!

Comment: Are there any large assets that could be optimized or loaded dynamically to reduce memory usage? Consider using packages like flutter_cache_manager to manage asset caching efficiently,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.